# Custom banner advertisment on iPhone/iPad application

Tags: iphone, ipad, banner

Is this allowed by Apple to put a custom sponsor banner like an advertisement in an application developed by myself ?

Comment: Not exactly a programming related question.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, why not? The iAd network only gives you a fast and easy implementation for bannering and such. But there are many other parties who provide mobile bannering or you can even use your own banner system. As long as the content of the banners don't conflict with the App store guidelines (pornography and such)

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. If you include the url to the iTunes page for the app you can even send the user to the advertised app from within your new app.

Comment: Yes,thank you for your answer, but I want to put an url to a product out of the iTunes, for example a cosmetic product (it will be link to a website for example ). This is what I meant

Comment: Ok - well you can certainly do that! You have apps such as the Carling iPint which is pretty much an advertisement wrapped around a small app

Answer (score 1):

I think you can.

You can happily use 3rd party services like http://www.flurry.com/ to pull in custom adverts.

You don't have to use Apple's iAd: http://advertising.apple.com/

You could write your own system to show your own specific advert.